# "Fatal error encountered during command execution." mysql-connector .net

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, mysql-connector

I am using following code:

```
MySqlTransaction trnData = pconDB.BeginTransaction();
MySqlCommand cmdData = new MySqlCommand();

cmdData.Connection = pconDB;
cmdData.CommandTimeout = plngQueryTimeOut;
cmdData.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmdData.CommandText = "CALL spsOME( 4, 'DATA', 389552022,@intOutReturn);";
cmdData.Transaction = trnData;
plngRecordsCount = cmdData.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Isn't `CALL` statement possible directly from .net library? The same query is working on workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Change two lines to this:

```
   cmdData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmdData.CommandText = "spsOME( 4, 'DATA', 389552022,@intOutReturn);";
```

You will also need to add a parameter to the Parameters collection of `cmData` for the `@intOutReturn` parameter. I won't give an example of this as the syntax varies with databases and I don't know what MySQL's looks like.

Also, this line:

```
cmdData.Transaction = trnData;
```

..is only necessary if you are doing other db operations which should be in the same transaction. If you're not, I'd leave that line out.

Comment: I want to execute multiple CALL statements like this.             `CALL spsOME( 4, 'DATA', 389552022,@intOutReturn); CALL spsOME( 4, 'DATA', 389552022,@intOutReturn);` Is it possible??

Comment: Sure. But open another question for that, showing your code.